# Where can i find java assignments/projects to test knowledge

Tags: java, projects-and-solutions

I remember when my friend was doing java course then in his last assignment he had one project which had to use almost everything from java. and that project was clearly explained how student should proceed and what it should suppose to do.

I want to develop some sort of that so that i can learn more. I have found that i learn fast when i develop some project using all techniques (like inheritance gui exceptions etc ) rather than doing small example from particular topic.

Any ideas or pdfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be to develop an **[Eclipse Cheat sheet](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-ua/proposals/cheatsheet/cheat_sheet_enhancements/cheatsheet_3.2_overview.html)** where you can compose small steps in order to complete a full course.

[image]

See [Cheat Sheet editor](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/composite_cs_editor/editor.htm) and [Cheat Sheet principle](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_cheatsheet.htm):

> In general, cheat sheets help guide users through a complex set of instructions.
>   There are two types of cheat sheets: simple and composite.
>   **Composite cheat sheets are used to organize and present tasks represented by simple cheat sheets to achieve a larger goal**.

Other endorsement/examples:

- [Cheat Sheet rocks!](http://blog.architexa.com/2010/11/eclipse-cheat-sheets-rock/)
- [Building your own Cheat Sheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/eclipse-cheat-sheets-092351.html)

Answer (score 3):

I usually learn the new technology the same way : create new project.

My suggestions:

### (A) Participate in a Developer Contest:

I have found that it helps me to participate in an ongoing contest related to that field/technology. For example, when I wanted to learn Android, I participated in Googleś android contest 2. Similarly, when I wanted to learn Samsung C++ Bada platform, I participated in Bada Worldwide Dev contest (I won a bada phone :-).

The idea is two-fold:
1. You have some deadline within which you *have* to finish the project. This means, each day you must work on it for at least 2-3 hours.
2. If you really do well in your project, you may win a prize. :-)

I found that if your goal is to learn advanced Java (not necessarily POJO), you can probably participate in Nokia-ATTś 10m contest for Nokia´s upcoming N8 device. Link: http://www.callingallinnovators.com/10m/

### (B) Try to look for some projects on the website : rentacoder.com

(now renamed: http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx ). 
I found that their are 92 open projects under the category Java"on that site: 
http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/misc/BidRequests/ShowBidRequests.asp?lngBidRequestListType=3&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=10&lngBidRequestCategoryId=9&optSortTitle=2&optBidRequestPhase=2&lngSortColumn=-6&blnModeVerbose=True&optBiddingExpiration=1
You may not win the bid, but you can get an idea as to what kind of project you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Give the [Facebook puzzles](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php) a shot
- Try solving the old problems from old ACM programming contests at [UVA Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/)

Both have automatic graders that verify the correctness of your solution and the latter will also tell you how your solution compares to others who have attempted the same problem.

Comment: Nah I've been this year to ACM central-eu finals and honestly, this is more like math/algorithm competion, not really helps you improving in specific language.